# Site-wide error message broadcast in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a single way of showing the user if there is an error with a $http call, and I currently invoke it by doing something like:

```
$http({

  //do stuff

}).
error(function(){
  $scope.$broadcast('error');
});
```

And I have a directive that listens for the the error with $on.

However I just end up repeating the $broadcast everywhere I use $http, is it possible to extend the default error callback to broadcast the error every time?

Comment: I would suggest to use a response [interceptor](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) instead. Let me code up a simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you use a response interceptor instead.

You can find the details on the [AngularJS API Reference](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#interceptors), but this is how it would work:

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').factory('myHttpErrorInterceptor', function ($q) {
    return {
        'responseError': function (rejection) {
            console.log('DEBUG: Status:', rejection.status);
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});

angular.module('app').config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpErrorInterceptor');
});

angular.module('app').run(function ($http) {
    $http.get('http://example.org/that-doesnt-exist');    
});
```

Instead of my `console.log`, you can broadcast your error instead.

You can find a live example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jaq5sZxaTJjrTAGFF7Sq?p=preview).